# UISearchBar Not shifting up

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

Somehow i dun know why does the default animation fails.

my Search bar did not shift up as it supposed to be.

the view is in UIView, i'm wondering if this is the problem.

Included the IB layout

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please elaborate the problem i m not understanding your problem

Comment: Hi vijay, when i tapped on the searchbar, it should push up like the 1st picture. however my searchbar(2nd picture)pushed up the nav bar, but did not move up to the top

Comment: What should push up?  The keyboard?  I still dont understand your problem.

Comment: post some relevant code. how you are initializing and handling delegate messages for the `UISearchDisplayController` and `UISearchBar` would help. Also anything related to laying your views.

Comment: the Searchbar should should pushup just like native tableview app.

Comment: Look at my answer, this is going to solve your question.

Comment: anybody know what is called when searchresult table are tapped

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The searchbar doesn't actually move in the 'push-up' animation. Rather it stays in place while the navbar goes up, thus pulling the rest of the view with it.  You should be able to move the search bar manually in code by registering as its delegate (UISearchBarDelegate) and responding to these calls.

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate Methods
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //move the search bar up to the correct location eg
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4
                 animations:^{ 
                     searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                  0,
                                                  searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                                  searchBar.frame.size.height);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     //whatever else you may need to do
                 }];
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //move the search bar down to the correct location eg
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4
                 animations:^{ 
                     searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                  /*SearchBar original Y*/,
                                                  searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                                  searchBar.frame.size.height);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     //whatever else you may need to do
                 }];
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks this is wat i wan to do :)

will award you the bounty in 7 hours time, can't award u now :(

Comment: it will be kind of you to help me solve this problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027984/how-to-have-a-overlay-on-top-of-a-select-uitabbar-item
 and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028411/which-event-get-called-when-you-click-on-the-uisearchbar-to-call-the-first-respo

Answer (score 2):

The best way to implement an `UISearchBar` and an `UISearchDisplayController` following Apple guidelines is looking at the example called [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848), the description says:

> Demonstrates how to search the contents of a UITableView using
>   UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController, effectively filtering in
>   and out the contents of that table. If an iPhone/iPod Touch
>   application has large amounts of table data, this sample shows how to
>   filter it down to a manageable amount if memory usage is a concern or
>   you just want users to scroll through less table content.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Elvis thanks for the answer, i'm been using search display controller.

Comment: Which is what my answer was five hours before

Answer (score 1):

In the first image of your question, you are showing a UISearchDisplayController being used. In order to achieve that exact animation, you will need to use a UISearchDisplayController and modify it's UISearchBar to look like the custom one you made. You can drag a UISearchDisplayController over in Interface Builder and then use code to change it's searchBar property.

`self.searchDisplayController.searchbar` will be what you modify if you have everything hooked up correctly in Interface BUilder.