# Why SearchBar of Search Display Controller is not moving up in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

On my `UIViewController`, I took `UISearchDisplayController` and `UITableView`. The SearchBar of `UISearchDisplayController` is outside of `UITableView` because I don't want to scroll SearchBar with TableView. When started typing some text, It looks fine in **iOS6** but in **iOS7** SearchBar does not move up and tableView comes over it. And after search button clicked, SearchBar goes out of screen and whole screen messed up. Why is this happening?

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this problem is stil up to date, but maybe someone will have the same question. The reason of this is that You are using UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.

If it makes no difference to You, use the UITableViewController. If You have some reasons, you'll have to move searchbar programatically in `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:searchBar` 
and `searchBarShouldEndEditing:searchBar`

Here's an example how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8042790/1293285